# In Excel, how to create a VBA that returns a data range from another sheet when data validation = to a certain choice?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation, visual-basic

I'm trying to return data (from A1:D14) on sheet 4 into A2:D:15 on sheet 1 when I select "A" on my data validation list located on Sheet 1 cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this on your `Sheet1 A2`

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=A, Sheet2!A2)
```

Expand the formula to `D15` so it now covers `A2:D15`.

This will work because you does not include `$` on the cell name, allowing Excel to automatically update the formula as you drag it down and right.